# Value disappears from QVector

Tags: c++, qt, dictionary, vector

I have the `QMap` with `QVector` inside:

```
QMap<QString, QMap<QGraphicsView*, QVector<float>>> graphs;
```

I'm trying to execute this code:

```
QVector<float>* graphValues = &(graphs.values()[i - values.count()].values()[0]);

graphValues->push_back(1234);

qDebug() << "=== Debug messages ===\r\n";
qDebug() << "i - values.count() = " << i - values.count();
qDebug() << "graphValues = " << graphValues;
qDebug() << "*graphValues = " << *graphValues;
qDebug() << "graphs = " << graphs;
qDebug() << "graphs.values()[i - values.count()].values()[0] = " << graphs.values()[i - values.count()].values()[0];
```

It gives me output:

```
i - values.count() =  0
graphValues =  0x2000e90
*graphValues =  QVector(1234)
graphs =  QMap(("tempgraph", QMap((QGraphicsView(0x1fb1920) ,  QVector() ) ) ))
graphs.values()[i - values.count()].values()[0] =  QVector()
```

So, where is my value? Using pointer i wait for my value in `graphs`, but it disappears.

Comment: What is `values` in `values.count` ?

Comment: It is other `QMap` with `count()` = `i` now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QMap::values()` method returns temporary object. You cannot change original data, by changing it. You should use iterators, or `QMap::operator[]` somehow.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using `QGraphicsView*` as key i successfully did it.

Comment: I think it would be better and more readable (and more OO) if you move that 'vector inside a map inside a map' variable into a class. But if you want to it like this then the answer is correct.